# iOS - Reload tableView on UISegmentedControl change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, reloaddata

I have a UITableView with one section, as following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.units){
        return [self.arrayTwo count];
    }else{
        return [self.arrayOne count];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 75.0;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", nil];
    UISegmentedControl *control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    [control setFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 10.0, 220.0, 30.0)];
    [control setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStylePlain];
    [control setEnabled:YES];
    [control setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [control addTarget:self action:@selector(testing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [control setSelectedSegmentIndex:self.units];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 45.0, 220.0, 30.0)];
    [label setText:@"String"];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    [headerView addSubview:control];
    [headerView addSubview:label];
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    return headerView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(self.units == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.arrayOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ kg", [self.arrayTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Where `self.units` is determined from the value of an NSUserDefaults variable.  The method called on change of the UISegnmentedControl is:

```
- (void) testing:(id)sender {
    int selected = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

    [self.userDefaults setInteger:selected forKey:@"SSTestVariable"];

    [self.userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Right now this all works great, but what I would like to add to the `testing` method is for the UITableView to reload and display the data for the selected item in the UISegmentedControl.  The reload can be instantaneous, or a fade-out and fade-in, or some other animation.  Doesn't matter.

I have tried placing

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

at the end of the `testing` method, but that doesn't do the trick.  Essentially, I need to go through the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again, load the cell textLabels with the corresponding data, and then reload the table view.

Thanks in advance.

Please note: I have changed the method and variable names specifically for this thread.  I do not regularly make a practice of naming things "arrayOne" or "testing," so please skip the naming conventions comments.

Comment: `reloadData` is the correct method - but I don't see any code to update `self.units` in your testing method

Comment: In the testing method you should update the self.units and then use relaodData. Oh @Paulw11 was faster than me :c

Comment: You're both right, that did the trick!  If one of you wants to make that an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData]; in your segmented control delegate method.

Comment: @VineeshTP that alone won't do it.  Lke Paul and Nils pointed out, I had to update `self.units` first, and then reload it.